# Error message: replacement has length zero

Tags: r, optimization

I am getting the error:

> Error in delta[i] <- (mkt - mod)^2 : replacement has length zero

I can not figure out why.

I am trying to generate a yield curve using the Nelson-Siegel-Svensson approach. The following is my code. I go by first inserting some previously interpolated swap rates and then calculating the yields  for 20 different maturities. I create then two functions to fit the curve, but I get the error message.

```
#input
swaps <- c ( -0.19 , -0.15 , -0.08 , 0.01 , 0.13 , 0.26,
                    0.39 , 0.52 ,0.64 , 0.75, 0.875, 0.93, 0.993333333, 1.0566666666,
             1.12, 1.15, 1.18, 1.21, 1.24, 1.27) / 100
#bootstrap
v <- c()
v[1] <- 1/(1+swaps[1])
v[2] <- (1-swaps[1]*v[1])/(1+swaps[1])
for(i in 3:length(swaps)){
  v[i] <- (1-swaps[i]*sum(v[1:(i-1)]))/(1+swaps[i])
}

#yields
y <- c()
y[1] <- swaps[1]
y[2] <- ((1+swaps[2])/(1-swaps[2]*v[1]))^(1/2)-1
for(k in 3:length(swaps)){
  y[k] <- ((1+swaps[k])/(1-swaps[k]*sum(v[1:(k-1)])))^(1/k)-1
}

#maturities
tau <- c(seq(1:length(y)))

#function
NSS = function(tau, parameters){
  beta0 = parameters[1]
  beta1 = parameters[2]
  beta2 = parameters[3]
  beta3 = parameters[4]
  tau1 = parameters[5]
  tau2 = parameters[6]
  r1 = tau/tau1
  r2 = tau/tau2
  rr1 = 1/r1
  rr2 = 1/r2
  delta = beta0 + beta1*exp(-r1) + beta2*(r1)*exp(-r1) +
  beta3*r2*exp(-r2)
  h = beta0 + beta1*rr1*(1-exp(-r1)) + beta2*(rr1*(1-exp(-r1))- exp(-r1))
  + beta3*(rr2*(1-exp(-r2))-exp(-r2))
  i0 = which (tau==0)
  delta[i0] = beta0+beta1
  h[i0] = beta0+beta1
  rate = exp(h/100) - 1
  v = exp(-h/100*tau)
  out = data.frame(delta=delta, h=h, rate=rate, v=v)
  return(out)
}

#function to estimate
f.est = function(parameters){
  par = parameters
  delta = array(0, dim = length(tau))
  for(i in 1: length(tau)){
    mod = NSS(tau[i], par)$delta
    mkt = y[i]
    delta[i] = (mkt-mod)^2
  }
  out=sum(delta)
  return(out)
}

#constraints
par0 = c(1, -2,5, 12, -16.405789, 1.2, 1.4)
plow = c(-5, -4, -100, -100, 0.1, 0.01)
pupp = c(400,1, 100, 100, 10, 10)
#optimal param
est <- optim(par=par0, fn=f.est, method="L-BFGS-B", lower = plow, upper = pupp)
#paramters Ns
beta0 = est$par[1]
beta1 = est$par[2]
beta2 = est$par[3]
beta3 = est$par[4]
tau1 = est$par[5]
tau2 = est$par[6]
par = c(beta0, beta1, beta2, beta3, tau1, tau2)
#extreme values
h0 = beta0+beta1
hinf = beta0

#maturities to plot
tau1 = c(0, seq(1:120))
outNSS1 <- NSS(tau1 , par)
outNSS1
#plot one curve
plot(tau1, outNSS1$rate*100, type = "l", xlab = "Time to maturity",
     ylab ="Spot rates", col ="blue")
grid()

#all curve
plot(tau1, outNSS1$h, type = "l", xlab = "Time to maturity",ylim = c(-0.2,2),
     ylab ="Yields", col ="blue")
lines(tau1, outNSS1$delta, col="mediumseagreen")
lines(tau1, outNSS1$rate*100, col="indianred4")
legend('bottomright', c("forward intensity", "spot rate", "annual rate"), bty = "n", lty =c(1,1,1),
       col=c("mediumseagreen", "blue", "indianred4"))
grid()
```

Comment: the problem is `mod` is NULL. The result of NSS function is a dataframe with four columns, none of them is called `tasso`, so this `NSS(tau[i], par)$tasso` cant work

Comment: I am trying to replicate https://www.scor.com/en/file/29901/download?token=yciTWcyU on page 118 I exactly copy the code, but is it a mistake in their code then?

Comment: I dont know what the program is supposed to do, there is definitely the same problem in the pdf code. To me the most probable solution is they changed the name of one of the columns in the NSS output and forgot to change the f.est code accordingly, you need to understand what column it is and modify the f.est code with the new column name

Comment: Is there a way to check the name or output of those columns since the code is not running=?

Comment: the name are here: `data.frame(delta=delta, h=h, rate=rate, v=v)`. to debug it is often useful to add print statements, for example before the line defining mod you could add `print(NSS(tau[i], par))`

Comment: hmm I tried all the variables, but none of them can replicate their graph for some reason.  Maybe there needs to be more changes, I also put the whole code in the question above.